# Running Selenium Tests using Jenkins and Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, jenkins

I have created a couple of Selenium Test Cases using java in Eclipse. I want to run these tests using Jenkins. I am also using Maven for the build Automation Tool. 
When I use the Build Now feature in Jenkins, I get a Build Success Message in the Console Output but the tests do not run.
I wanted to know how should I invoke the Main Method from Jenkins. Is there some plugin that I need to add to my pom file.

[image]

[enter image description here][2]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf9S8.jpg)

I am copying the present POM file below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>SecondOne</groupId>
<artifactId>Project2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>                      
    <dependency>                
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>                              
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>                              
        <version>2.45.0</version>                               
    </dependency>               
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jopendocument</groupId>
    <artifactId>jOpenDocument</artifactId>
    <version>1.3b1</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>             
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>                             
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>                               
        <version>5.5.4</version>                                                                        
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
  <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
  <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>               
</dependencies>
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          <mainClass>src.main.java.pack1.FirstClass</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.1</version>
      <inherited>true</inherited>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Please note that I am **not** using TestNG or any other common Testing Frameworks.
Thanks a ton for the help

Comment: Why would jenkins run your program?

Comment: what is the command you have used to build your mvn program in Jenkins? And what you want to know - run test cases or find out main class?

Comment: @RavindraDevadiga - I have used the 'Build Now' feature present in Jenkins Dashboard. Also, in the Configure Tab for the Project in Jenkins, I have added the path to the POM File and I have set the 'Goal and Options' field to clean test. I want to run the test cases.

Comment: @tkausl - I am trying to run my Selenium Tests using Jenkins so that I can schedule the test runs.

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is a class which simulates your test flow execution. Jenkins can only compile this,it won't execute it.

If you want to run test cases as part of your maven build (Command: mvn test) then you should follow the Junit framework structure (refer this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/index.htm)) and implement your logic there.

You also have to include **maven-surefire-plugin** in your pom.xml (which you have already done in this case)

Comment: Thanks Ravindra. One last question - What if I don't use Maven, will I be able to run the Selenium Tests through Jenkins (without using JUnit or TestNG) or is that not possible as well?

Comment: Nope, you cannot run as test case until unless you follow the Junit framework structure. It doesn't matter whether you use maven or not.

Comment: Thanks Ravindra. Appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Its better to use testng because you will need it when you run your testcases that is included in your testng.xml file, through your pom.xml file. You need to create testng.xml in your project. Also don't forget to include your test cases in your testng.xml file.

Include compiler and surefire plugins in your pom.xml file under build tag.

```
<build>
 <pluginManagement>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.2</version>
   <configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
   </configuration>
  </plugin>
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.12</version>
  <inherited>true</inherited>
  <configuration>
   <forkMode>never</forkMode>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
     <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
   </configuration>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
 </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Now go to your project and Build. :)